# Autowire specific inner bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an interface called `HttpClient`, and two `beans` implementation of the bean,

```
 public interface HttpClient {
    String bla();
}
```

```
@Component
public class HttpClientImpl implements HttpClient {
    @Override
    public String bla() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class HttpClientMock implements HttpClient {
    @Override
    public String bla() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And now I have a wrapper for this bean that injects the HttpClient

```
@Component
public class Wrapper {
    @Autowired HttpClient httpClient;
}
```

Is there any way to choose when I inject the `Wrapper`

```
@Autowired Wrapper wrapper;
```

to choose the specific implementation for the `HttpClient`, I mean if I want to inject the `HttpClientMock`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Component("httpClient")
public class HttpClientImpl implements HttpClient {
    @Override
    public String bla() {
        return null;
    }
}

@Component("httpClientMock")
public class HttpClientMock implements HttpClient {
    @Override
    public String bla() {
        return null;
    }
}

@Component
public class Wrapper {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("httpClient")
    HttpClient httpClient;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("httpClientMock")
    HttpClient httpClientMock;
}
```

Here it seems you need your httpClient for testing, In that case i wouldnt say to do above way, rather create profiles as given below (you can have different profile for other ones) and when you run your spring application , run it in test profile. Find more information about [spring profiles  here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

```
@Component("httpClientMock")
@Profile("test")
public class HttpClientMock implements HttpClient {
    @Override
    public String bla() {
        return null;
    }
}
```